# $f(x,y)= xy $ conditions to finding limit

Tags: limits

context: currently learning about 'definition of limits' as applied to functions of 2 variables.

$f(x,y)= xy $ consider if: $(x,y)-> (1,2)$

In finding the limit using 'definition of limits'; my notes then write the "statement": $|y|<3$ if $|y-2|<1$.

I agree that the above statement, by itself is correct, however how is it deduced? As in how did the finding of the limit lead to the inferences in the 'statement.'

Comment: here is a link to the notes: http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/Chen-notes/lnfycfolder/fyc17.pdf page 2 Example 17.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without words:
$$
|y-2|<1 \Rightarrow |y| \leq |y-2|+2 < 3.
$$

Comment: yes i agree with what you wrote; but how do i know abs(y-2) <1

Comment: I guess it is a typical "condition without loss of generality". Since $y \to 2$, you can always consider those values of $y$ that live in some neighborhood of $2$. Here the neighborhood is the interval $(1,3)$.